# Best books or resources on web application security and user authentication?

Tags: security

I'm looking to learn more about web application security and user authentication as it applies in 2013 and beyond across technologies like PHP, Java + Spring, Python + Django/Flask, Ruby on Rails, and all modern application frameworks.

Anyone have any good suggestions?

I gleaned some from [a popular security.stackexchange post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/419/if-you-could-have-only-one-book-on-web-security-what-would-it-be) but most of these are dated:

- The Web Application Hacker's Handbook: Discovering and Exploiting Security Flaws
- The Tangled Web by Michal Zalewski
- Writing Secure Code v2 from MS Press

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

We have used spring security (Acegi Security) in various features like ( Database Authentication, LDAP Authentication, Web Authentication, Domain Authentication) in my project.

Please find the references.

http://www.springsource.org/spring-security

http://www.springsecuritybook.com/

http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html